# How to create page-control modal view from tab-bar button

Tags: uigesturerecognizer, uitabbar, swipe, uipagecontrol

I would like to implement a modal view similar to the screenshot below.

When the user presses a tab-bar (help) button, I want the view to appear showing the first of multiple pages of help screens, with the page-control dots for sequential navigation via swipe gestures left and right to navigate to each help page.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazing what an extra bit of research will produce. Found examples of using UIScrollView with UIPageControl to achieve something similar.